# Как конвертировать данные в кодировке Windows-1251 в юникод в Python без ошибок?

Tags: python, кодировка, исключения, unicode, windows-1251

Как решить проблему с кодировкой в Python при обработке данных, полученных с сайта в кодировке Windows-1251? При попытке записать их в файл или вывести на экран вылетает исключение UnicodeEncodeError. Как правильно конвертировать данные в юникод, чтобы избежать ошибки?

Comment: Чтобы что-то сказать нужен код и данные(сайт), а по этим данным предположительно, не правильно выбрана кодировка.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806980/python-how-to-convert-from-windows-1251-to-unicode